Getting "Attempted import error: '__CLIENT_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_WARN_USERS_THEY_CANNOT_UPGRADE' " in react app
I am receiving the following error when trying to run my React app:

react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
Attempted import error: '__CLIENT_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_WARN_USERS_THEY_CANNOT_UPGRADE' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'React').

Tried deleting yarn.lock file and node_modules folder.
Tried updating react and react-dom
Tried re-running the Azure build pipeline but the result is same and there is no code change in Azure pipeline. I just tried running the Azure build pipeline again manually.
Tried deleting yarn.lock file and node_modules folder.
Also tried re-running the Azure build pipeline but the result is same and there is no code change in Azure pipeline. I just tried running the Azure build pipeline again manually.

Usually you get this kind of error when there is a version mismatch between packages.
As a first attempt, if you haven’t already tried, would be to also clear the cache with yarn cache clean or npm cache clean -f
If you are using yarn, I suggest you try running yarn why and check for any package that might be “clashing” with react like for instance any libraries that manipulate React internals or UI component libraries.
